# How to create shape flow in convolutional neural network using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I create cnn on my own dataset, with MNIST tutorial as helper. 
My layers was created with colorful images resized to 28x28 but when i resize image to 32x32, i get

```
incompatible shapes: [400] vs. [100]
     [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ArgMax, ArgMax_1)]]
```

I debug all layers and all seems be ok, input has correct 100 images and 100 labels

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, cons.IMAGE_SIZE, cons.IMAGE_SIZE, 3])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, cons.LABELS_NUMB])

K = 4
L = 8
M = 12
N = 200


x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, cons.IMAGE_SIZE, cons.IMAGE_SIZE, 3])

################## first ##############

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 3, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

################## second ##############

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

################## fully connected 3 ##############

W_fc1 = weight_variable([4 * 4 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 4*4*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

################ dropout  4 #################

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

################## fully connected 5 ##############

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, cons.LABELS_NUMB])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([cons.LABELS_NUMB])

Y = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=Y))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for i in range(10000):
    img, lb = fileCreation.next_batch(100, images32, labels)
    if i % 100 == 0:
      train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
          x: img, y_: fileCreation.dense_to_one_hot(lb, cons.LABELS_NUMB),  keep_prob: 1.0})
      print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: img, y_: fileCreation.dense_to_one_hot(lb, cons.LABELS_NUMB),  keep_prob: 0.5})

  print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: test_images32,
                                                      y_: fileCreation.dense_to_one_hot(test_labels, cons.LABELS_NUMB), keep_prob: 0.1}))
```

LABELS_NUM = 15
IMAGE_SIZE = 32

How can i change my layers, than my y_ was equal 100 not 400 size?

Edit additional method to resize image

```
def resize_images(test_images):
    return [skimage.transform.resize(image, (const.IMAGE_SIZE, const.IMAGE_SIZE))
            for image in test_images]
```

Comment: How do you "resize" the image? If by "resize" you mean "change the number of pixels but have the image look mostly the same", `tf.reshape` is not what you want to use. You should use something like https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i used skimage method to resize batch of image. So its look ok

Comment: Is the problem solved? If not, I am quite confused because the numbers you give, the code, and the error message don't pass basic sanity checks. The error is from the Equal operation (if you post a full error back trace, it can be useful) with INT64, this is probably comparing your Y and y_.  But Y should have dimension of 15 since it is constructed by adding `b_fc2`, which is `bias_variable([cons.LABELS_NUMB])`. I would suggest printing the shapes of all layers to see where your expectation does not match reality.